# I want to show 2nd drp down value if 1st one is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two issues:

1) I want to show the values of the 2nd drop down if the first drop
    down value is selected

2) I want pass the DataFeild value of the selected item in the first
    drop down as a parameter to the 2nd drop down. (it is throwing
    outofrange exception)

```
<div class="colmd-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 responsive-filterbar">
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="drpCRHCompetencyName" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="form-control" DataTextField="title" DataValueField="responsibilityID"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<div class="colmd-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 responsive-filterbar">
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="drpCRHCompetencyLevel" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="form-control" DataTextField="level" DataValueField="skillLevleID"></asp:DropDownList>
</div> 

var competencyName = CompetencyManager.GetSFIACompetencies();
drpCRHCompetencyName.DataSource = competencyName;
drpCRHCompetencyName.DataBind();

var competencyLevel = CompetencyManager.GetLevelByCompetency(drpCRHCompetencyName.SelectedValue);
drpCRHCompetencyLevel.DataSource = competencyLevel;
drpCRHCompetencyLevel.DataBind();
```

Now I am getting error if I put drpCRHCompetencyName.SelectedValue as a parameter. Can some suggest me the right way please

Comment: What is your question? The post looks like a request for code-writing service. Please clarify. Best regards,

Comment: My question is "SelectedValue" is not working, as far as i know it selects the datafield value of the item that is selected. but it is giving error

Comment: Can you post the code of what CompetencyManager.GetLevelByCompetency() is doing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check first if the following line returns any valid object to be used for DataBinding:

```
var competencyLevel = CompetencyManager.GetLevelByCompetency(drpCRHCompetencyName.SelectedValue);
```

Hope this may help. Best regards,